# .drop doesn't drop/delete row

Tags: python, pandas

File|Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


csvFilePath = "clean_data.csv"
csvDF = pd.read_csv(csvFilePath, header=0)
csvDF.fillna(0, inplace=True)
def addEntry():
    rowValues = input("Enter the row values separated by commas: ").split(",")
    csvDF.loc[len(csvDF.index)] = rowValues
    print("Row added!")
    print(csvDF)

def deleteEntry():
    entryState = input("Enter the state of the entry to delete: ")
    csvDF.drop(csvDF[(csvDF['state']==entryState)].index, inplace=True)
    print("Row Deleted!")
    print(csvDF)

query = int(input("Enter number: "))
if query==1:
    addEntry()
elif query==2:
    deleteEntry()
```

Function `deleteEntry()` doesn't delete the entry, or it doesn't seem to be deleted. I've done this in an IPython Notebook and it work fine there but doesn't seem to work here.

Comment: Try `csvDF = csvDF[csvDF['state'] != entryState]`

Comment: he already has `inplace=True`

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych won't that delete all rows that don't match entryState?

Comment: No, that keeps all the rows that don't match `entryState`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Values from clipboard, which were taken with function 'input' always have type string. If you have your numbers in column 'state' as integers you should change the type of the input.

For example:

```
entryState = int(input("Enter the state of the entry to delete: "))
```

Also there could be a problem with additional symbols when you use addEntry. That could cause this problem too. So maybe you should change type of enter too:

```
rowValues = [int(x) for x in rowValues]
```

But if you want to use strings in your data frame you should do it carefully, because for example, if your input is **1, 2, 3, 4** when you are adding new row, you will get spaces in your values. So you can try to use regrew to clean your input, if you like.

Also, I noticed a typo in your code in function add entry:

```
csvDF.loc[len(csvDF.index)] = rowValues
```

I guess you should use this instead:

```
csvDF.loc[len(csvDF.index)+1] = rowValues
```

Because in other way you will just replace the last row with new values.

With all of these fixes you code work fine for me.